# How to click the Calendar image icon using selenium-webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried many ways but it did't work for me. please help on this

**DOM area:**

```
<td>
<input name="ctl00$cntMainContent$txtStartDate" type="text" id="ctl00_cntMainContent_txtStartDate" class="clsTextBox" onkeydown="javascript:return false;" onpaste="javascript:return false;">                                
<img id="ctl00_cntMainContent_imgStartDate" src="../Images/calendar.gif" align="absbottom">
</td>
```

below are the areas i have tried,
**Normal Click method:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_cntMainContent_imgStartDate']")).click();
```

**Javascriptexecutor:**

```
public void Javascript_Click()
    {           
        JavascriptExecutor executor= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;            executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('ctl00_cntMainContent_imgStartDate').click()");     
    }
```

**Actions:**

```
public void Action_Click()
        {
            Actions act = new Actions(driver);          act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cntMainContent_imgStartDate"))).click().build().perform();
        }
```

Comment: @Anyone...Please help me on above

Answer (score 0):

As the element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("td img[id$='cntMainContent_imgStartDate'][src$='Images/calendar.gif']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td//img[contains(@id, 'cntMainContent_imgStartDate') and contains(@src, 'Images/calendar.gif')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: i tried this..but not worked for me.  showing no error and no failures

Comment: @DebanjanB...Any other ways to interact with that element

Comment: @Satya You only told us _it did't work for me_ but you haven't told us what went wrong or shared the error stack trace. So it's difficult to construct a canonical answer.

Comment: It is not throwing any error for those click statements

Comment: When i highlight the element using Javascriptexector it is highlighting but not clicking if we write the click method....really awaiting the suggestions to solve this...r

Answer (score 0):

Try following approach:

1. With **`Actions`**

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td img#ctl00_cntMainContent_imgStartDate"));
   Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
   actions.moveToElement(element)
       .click(element)
       .build()
       .perform();
   ```
2. With **`JavascriptExecutor`**

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td img#ctl00_cntMainContent_imgStartDate"));
   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
   ```

Comment: Hi frianH, 
Thanks for the reply..
i have tried the above 2 approaches as well but no use.

Comment: @Satya is possible to share the site?

Comment: @FrianH..Due to company security reasons can't able to share the site